# Is it possible to limit my requests from Amadeus API

Tags: api, amadeus

on the "Production Commercial Plan usage" is is possible to set a limit for my requests to prevent from bugs/ hackers to make endless requests? otherwise its kind of risky to my billing account.

Comment: I think this is more a question for Amadeus directly rather than StackOverflow, sorry, unless there's a documented feature in the API that does this. There may be steps like IP restrictions you can use to protect yourself from third parties using your API key, but use through your site could still be open to abuse / bugs. You could start monitoring how many API requests users make per browser session, and then set a hard limit per session significantly above that? (And alerts so you can check if it's a genuine user or abuse)

Comment: @Rup Thanks for your answer.
I didn't worked too much with APIs before, isn't it like a standard in this world? cuz its kind of a pit without a bottom.